# React Native Play RTSP Stream from IP Camera

Tags: ios, react-native, rtsp

I would like to play video stream (h264) through RTSP protocol from IP/Network in iOS device. I am using React Native.

I have tried several React Native packages as below, but not manage to make it work.

- react-native-vlcplayer
- react-native-pili
- react-native-pxplayer

The closest package that I think might work is react-native-vlcplayer, but it seems to be abandoned.

Any recommendation?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, What are you using now? Did you find any libraries?

Comment: No luck so far. We are forced to use mpeg over http at the moment, until we have a breakthrough.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/ksvc/react-native-video-player, It's working out. But getting an issue with prod build

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely look into that.

Comment: Even prod build issue is fixed by

https://github.com/ksvc/react-native-video-player/issues/7#issuecomment-398658697

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ksyvideo this library

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-vlcplayer for streaming from the IP camera on iOS and react-native-vlc-player for streaming on Android.

When you do "react-native link", don't forget to check the header search path and framework search path inside the RTVLCPlayer sub project. It is generally hardcoded. Change it accordingly and your code should work.

You can also refer [this link](https://medium.com/mobil-dev/lets-make-a-video-player-app-e759c165fd58) if you are building on iOS.